# How to initialize function type parameter in Scala class?

Tags: scala

For example I have a code like this:

```
class Foo(name: String = "", callback: String => String) {

  def doCallback(arg: String): String = {
    callback(arg)
  }
}
```

Questions:

**1.** In `Foo` class constructor, how to give `callback` parameter a default value? Is it okay to set it to `null`? Or is there better alternative?

```
class Foo(name: String = "", callback: String => String = null) {
  ...
}
```

**2.** If answer of question no. 1 is not a `null`, how to do a check of `callback` before calling it inside the `doCallback` method? For example, suppose `null` is acceptable, I might do it like this:

```
class Foo(name: String = "", callback: String => String = null) {

  def doCallback(arg: String): String = {
    if (callback != null) callback(arg) else ""  // the checking of not null
  }
}
```

Comment: define a closure that returns null ass default parameter

Comment: Whenever possible do not use `null`, use `Option` instead

Comment: @Andrey: care to give an example? Maybe you could put it on pastebin.

Comment: Also, this option is superior to pastebin for small amounts of code http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_scala_online.php

Comment: @Andrey: I prefer Ideone.com. I just tried tutorialspoint, it didn't work when executing the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Foo(name: String = "", callback: Option[String => String] = None) {

def doCallback(arg: String): String = {
  val call: Option[String] = callback.map(c => c(arg)) // which will either be None or Some(String)

  call match {
      case Some(s: String) => s
      case None => null
    }
  }
}
```

Of course if you change the signature of `doCallback` to `Option[String]` you won't have to do pattern matching.

In general avoiding having `null`s in Scala is a good practice. One benefit of which is not getting `NullPointerException`s.

This approach however does force you to pass your `callback` on class instantiation within `Some()`.

Or, more in line with your original request:

```
class Foo(name: String = "", callback: String => Option[String] = {(s) => None}) {

  def doCallback(arg: String): String = {
    val call: Option[String] = callback(arg)

    call match {
      case Some(s: String) => s
      case None => null
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Which one is preferable between two given example? The second one made me have to pass the callback that return `Option[String]` when instantiating the `Foo` class.

Comment: If I use your 2nd example, then I should use the code like this? `println(new Foo(callback = s => Some("Hi " + s)).doCallback("Scala"))`

Comment: Yes, that appears correct. Which one you prefer fully depends on the context that you are writing the code in.

Comment: If you have a default function that you use almost exclusively, making it the default in the second example is probably better.

Comment: But if in most cases you don't have a callback at all, the first example is probably better.

Comment: Do you think it's good to wrap the other property with Option too? For ex: `name: Option[String] = None`. If not, I better set the default value for `name` to empty string (`""`) or `null` from scala perspective?

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, it's good to wrap everything with `Option`.
But if you just want the default result to be `""`, things can be a bit easier:

```
val alwaysEmpty = { given: String => "" }

class Foo(val doCallback: String => String = alwaysEmpty)
```

Comment: You said `it's good to wrap everything with Option`. I'm curious, for other class's property like `name: String = ""`, do you think I better wrap it with `Option` too? Thus: `name: Option[String] = None`

Comment: It depends on what `""` means in each situation. If *null* and *empty* are both described by `""` yet considered as two different things, then they shouldn't be put in `""` but respectively `""` and `Option[String]`. If *null* and *empty* are the same thing, then `""` can be used for both.

Comment: I mean... if you're not going to distinguish `""` and `None`, then it can stay as `String`. If `""` has two different meanings, then it should be wrapped by `Option` to express one of them as `None`.